# Can I obtain the dispersion relation boosting the rest frame solution?

Tags: special-relativity, mass, field-theory, dispersion

I have some complicated relativistic coupled wave equation for a scalar field $\psi$ and a 2-tensor field $h^{\mu\nu}$. I'm not able to find the dispersion relation for a general momentum $p^\mu$, so I was thinking to first find the rest mass, setting $p^\mu = (\omega, \vec{p})$ to $(E, \vec{0})$, and then apply some Lorentz boost to find the dispersion relation.

Is it actually a possible procedure or am I saying heresies? How should I do it, in case? I was thinking to apply the boost to the fields, for example $\psi(x) = A(p) e^{i(\omega t - p^i x_i )}$ (where I set $p^i$ to zero and $\omega$ to the value of the rest mass)